# Installed MySQL but command is not found

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mysql

I just installed MySQL server on my Ubuntu laptop, but looks like that "mysql" command in the terminal does not work properly.

Looks like that MySQL is not installed in "usr/bin" folder. How can I install MySQL is "usr/bin" folder?

I would appreciate any help.

**Installation command:**

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

**What I tried:**

`mysql`

and

`sudo mysql -u root -p`

**I'm getting an error message like down below:**

`Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:`

**sudo service mysql status output:**

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-05-15 20:18:49 EDT; 23min ago
   Main PID: 1031 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 37 (limit: 4485)
     Memory: 393.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─1031 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

**whereis mysql output:**

`mysql: /usr/lib/mysql /etc/mysql`

`which mysql` doesn't do anything

**Edit:**

mysql-client is installed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client-core-8.0 is already the newest version (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Is the `mysql-client` package (and its dependencies) installed?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes.  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client-core-8.0 is already the newest version (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
mysql-client-core-8.0 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].